# PyCharm Django project fails to run with debugging

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

For quite a while I have this weird problem on my Windows 10 machine. When trying to launch a Django server with (and sometimes even without) debugging on PyCharm, I get this error:

```
...
pydev debugger: process 10532 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.8233.8)
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

That's how it looks without debugging:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\bin\runnerw.exe" D:\project\env\Scripts\python.exe D:/project/manage.py runserver 80

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The strangest thing is that if I re-run, some of the times (1 success in about 4-6 reruns) it will launch successfully. I also couldn't reproduce this problem without PyCharm.

Specs: Windows 10 Pro, Pycharm (this happens on versions 5.x through 2016.3) x86 and x64 versions, Python 3.5x, Django 1.8-1.10.x.

Any ideas why this happens or how to get some more detailed info about the crash?

**EDIT** This is what the Event Viewer reports about the error:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.5.1150.1013, time stamp: 0x566391f0
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57898db2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000b6d95
Faulting process ID: 0x1b30
Faulting application start time: 0x01d251286ca8ada3
Faulting application path: D:\project\env\Scripts\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report ID: b23376d6-cf66-4d83-8781-cd22311e0f9e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**EDIT 2** I've narrowed down the problem. The error appears to originate from `restart_with_reloader` in `autoreload.py` after this statement:

```
def restart_with_reloader():
    while True:
        args = [sys.executable] + ['-W%s' % o for o in sys.warnoptions] + sys.argv
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            args = ['"%s"' % arg for arg in args]
        new_environ = os.environ.copy()
        new_environ["RUN_MAIN"] = 'true'

        # this line crashes the whole script
        # I guess the problem arises in native code
        exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
        # debugger disconnects here

        if exit_code != 3:
            return exit_code
```

Maybe someone from the Python community has seen something similar?

Comment: You can have problem if you run several instances of your server (listening on the same port number). Make sure all running application are stopped before launching.

Comment: Your Python executable (`D:\project\env\Scripts\python.exe`) calls the module `C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll`, and raise an exception. I suggest you to create your virtualenv again and retry.

Comment: Nope, one server, one port, one PyCharm instance... As you can guess from the path, I am using virtualenv.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior on the command line (out of PyCharm)?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the post, the problem only persists when running *with* PyCharm.

Comment: The error possibly means that `you tried accessing memory space where you have no access to`. Can you post your configuration? Does the error come when you run PyCharm as admin?

Comment: I haven't tried running it as admin but as I've mentioned, the server sometimes runs without errors (I probably wouldn't be able to do that if the problem was user elevation). The configuration is simple: `http://127.0.0.1:80`, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ta.conf.settings.dev; PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, Python 3.5.1 with virtualenv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### tl;dr solution

To `Environment variables` in `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog add this pair:

`=C:` `c:\''`

[image]

---

I have submitted a ticket to JetBrains YouTrack and this is actually a problem with how Windows handles command line environment variables. You can find a workaround for the problem here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17069

Excerpt from JetBrains dev comment:

> Guys, I just found a bug in Windows and Microsoft CRT:)
> Try to add following env variable to environment variables in run config =C:  = c:``
> Yes,  =C: is NAME and  c:`` is value.

Comment: This was giving me nightmares.  The bug is only for Windows 10 AFAIK. The environment setting is in your run configurations.

Comment: This had me stumped. Nice find!

Comment: @Jesuisme Same problem persists with Windows 8/8.1.

Comment: @Crossfire Thanks for the update.  Others on my team using Windows 7 Pro don't have this issue.  Maybe its machine specific.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with PyCharm and Django. It's caused by running the auto reload feature of Django under PyCharm. I run PyCharm as admin as Jithin Pavithran suggested in the comment and problem was solved. You can also turn on "No reload" in PyCharm Django server configuration.